# OpenOfficeDocumentConverter - HTML -> RTF - conversion failed: could not load input document

Tags: java, converters, rtf, openoffice.org

I'm using jodconverter to convert RTF files to HTML.  Most of the time it works fine. Sometimes, it fails with the following exception:

```
com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: conversion failed: could not load input document
    at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.loadAndExport(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:134)
    at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convertInternal(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:120)
    at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:104)
    at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convertInternal(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:88)
    at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:82)
    at ...
```

I've seen other people reporting this exception when there is a component of OpenOffice missing (such as writer or calc).  I've already installed all the components.  And as I mentioned before, most of the time it seems to work.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I had the problem today. The reason was a full temp-directory because of the ODF-directories